# Visual Studio Code explorer view scrolling

Tags: visual-studio-code

My project contains a LOT of folders, many of which I routinely have open, making for a lengthy explorer view. I find scrolling this view quite frustrating for two reasons:

1. There is no equivalent of the editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity setting for the explorer view. I'm also generally happy with the scroll speed for my mouse in other applications, so don't want to go messing with a system wide setting to compensate for VSC.
2. The scrollbar is frustratingly difficult to grab at and requires precise mouse placement. The number of times I accidentally grab at the slider and resize the view rather than scroll it is ridiculous.

I've found no useful extension to help in this matter. Has anybody any suggestions? I'll raise an enhancement request in Github if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 shortcuts that can speed up navigation between files:

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd> you can browse a history of your last viewed files. Great for switching around when working on multiple files.

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (`Go to File...` command) you can quickly go to a file by name. You can also search for files inside folders like this: `folder/subfolder/file.ext`. This is great if you know what you are looking for.

Source and more navigation tips: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_quick-file-navigation

Comment: Thanks, yes I do use Ctrl+P often for sure. However, the detractor from this for me is that it takes some time after I open VSC before it has properly cached all of the filenames, so often I am left hanging for sometime before it will find the file I'm looking for. Other times, it's just easier to scroll the explorer list also anyway eg. I know the location but can't recall the exact filename, or the filename is so common that it is easier to scroll than try typing enough parent folder names to get a proper hit.

Answer (score 2):

This PR in vscode 1.59 may have fixed this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/110059/commits/61efc577e038ac772f12511fb823de27296dbc69

New settings:

```
workbench.list.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity
workbench.list.fastScrollSensitivity
```

Comment: Excellent! I'll give those a try, thanks.